# Sum dates with different timestamps and picking the min date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Beginner here. I want to have only one row for each delivery date but it is important to keep the hours and the minutes. I have the following table in Oracle (left): 
[image]

As you can see there are days that a certain SKU (e.g SKU A) was delivered twice in the same day. The table on the right is the desired result. Essentially, I want to have the quantities that arrived on the 28th summed up and in the Supplier_delivery column I want to have the earliest delivery timestamp. 
I need to keep the hours and the minutes otherwise I know I could achieve this by writing sth like:
 
SELECT  SKU, TRUNC(TO_DATE(SUPPLIER_DELIVERY), 'DDD'), SUM(QTY) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY SKU , TRUNC(TO_DATE(SUPPLIER_DELIVERY), 'DDD')
 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT SKU, MIN(SUPPLIER_DELIVERY), SUM(QTY)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY SKU, TRUNC(SUPPLIER_DELIVERY);
```

This assumes that `SUPPLIER_DELIVERY` is a date and does not need to be converted to one.  But it would work with `TO_DATE()` in the `GROUP BY` as well.